# Google Translate API - detect language + translate document (xlsx, csv)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, translation, google-translate, google-translation-api

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Translation API for translating an excel (or csv) document that includes text in multiple languages and my target language is english.

I would like to use "Translate text in batches (Advanced edition only)" code sample (link here: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/samples/translate-v3-batch-translate-text) but in the code sample is a line that defines the source language so there can only be one source language.

But I need to detect the langugage first in the document and then translate the text to english. There is code sample for detecting language in a simple string of a text "Detecting languages (Advanced)" (link: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/detecting-language-v3) but I need to combine the first code sample that translates documents (but only has one source language defined) with the ability to detect language instead of having one source language defined.

Is there this type of code sample in the resources? How could this be solved?

Here is the sample code in question:

```
from google.cloud import translate


def batch_translate_text(
    input_uri="gs://YOUR_BUCKET_ID/path/to/your/file.txt",
    output_uri="gs://YOUR_BUCKET_ID/path/to/save/results/",
    project_id="YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    timeout=180,
):
    """Translates a batch of texts on GCS and stores the result in a GCS location."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "us-central1"
    # Supported file types: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    gcs_source = {"input_uri": input_uri}

    input_configs_element = {
        "gcs_source": gcs_source,
        "mime_type": "text/plain",  # Can be "text/plain" or "text/html".
    }
    gcs_destination = {"output_uri_prefix": output_uri}
    output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination}
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/language
    operation = client.batch_translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "source_language_code": "en",
            "target_language_codes": ["ja"],  # Up to 10 language codes here.
            "input_configs": [input_configs_element],
            "output_config": output_config,
        }
    )

    print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
    response = operation.result(timeout)

    print("Total Characters: {}".format(response.total_characters))
    print("Translated Characters: {}".format(response.translated_characters))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to pass array of values to field [source_language_code](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/batchTranslateText#request-body) using `batchTranslateText`. What I could suggest is to perform `detectLanguage` and `translateText` per file.

What the code below does is:

1. It extracts the content to be translated. For testing purposes the the csv files used only have 1 column and content for sample1.csv is in `tl`(Tagalog) and sample2.csv is in `es`(Spanish).
2. Pass the extracted content to `detect_language()` to get detected language code.
3. Pass all the required parameters to `translate_text()` to translate

NOTE: The code below is only tested using csv files with one column. Edit the code at `main()` to pattern on what column you would like to extract data.

```
from google.cloud import translate
import csv


def listToString(s):
    """ Transform list to string"""
    str1 = " "
    return (str1.join(s))

def detect_language(project_id,content):
    """Detecting the language of a text string."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
    location = "global"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    response = client.detect_language(
        content=content,
        parent=parent,
        mime_type="text/plain",  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
    )

    for language in response.languages:
        return language.language_code


def translate_text(text, project_id,source_lang):
    """Translating Text."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
    location = "global"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    # Detail on supported types can be found here:
    # https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [text],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
            "source_language_code": source_lang,
            "target_language_code": "en-US",
        }
    )

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print("Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))
        
def main():

    project_id="your-project-id"
    csv_files = ["sample1.csv","sample2.csv"]
    # Perform your content extraction here if you have a different file format #
    for csv_file in csv_files:
        csv_file = open(csv_file)
        read_csv = csv.reader(csv_file)
        content_csv = []

        for row in read_csv:
            content_csv.extend(row)
        content = listToString(content_csv) # convert list to string
        detect = detect_language(project_id=project_id,content=content)
        translate_text(text=content,project_id=project_id,source_lang=detect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

**sample1.csv:**

```
kamusta
ayos
```

**sample2.csv:**

```
cómo estás
okey
```

**Output using the code above:**

```
Translated text: how are you okay
Translated text: how are you ok
```

Comment: 1/2

Thank you very much for your answer Ricco D.

I've tried to run it with my sample file and got an error message: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" (line 57 & 69)

My file is located at google cloud platform's cloud storage (bucket) and I have an empty folder for exported file in separate bucket.

I also tried replacing "your-project-id" at project_id="your-project-id" with the actual name of  my project-id and also with just "project-id" as project-id is defined in my json file

I'd like to ask two additional questions if possible (continues in 2/2)

Comment: 2/2

1) Is it possible to exchange "import csv" with a path to the source location of my csv file (input_uri="gs://YOUR_BUCKET_ID/path/to/your/file.txt") and also define a location where the new translated file would be exported? ( output_uri="gs://YOUR_BUCKET_ID/path/to/save/results/")

2) You mentioned in your note that "The code below is only tested using csv files with one column. Edit the code at main() to pattern on what column you would like to extract data." 
How should I edit the code at main() in case of having a csv file with (for example) 10 columns and 10 rows?

Thank you!

Comment: I created an updated question for this feed in regards to Reading and Writing to Cloud Storage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565106/google-translate-api-reading-and-writing-to-cloud-storage-python

Comment: 1.) You got a great answer from your created question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565106/google-translate-api-reading-and-writing-to-cloud-storage-python. 2.) This is difficult to answer since, this will depend on how you would like to parse your data. Would you like to combine all 10 rows and 10 columns into 1 string? Do you want to combine string per row? Per column? There are also multiple ways to do this. What I could suggest for you is to determine your requirements and read through how to parse CSV files. Like this article https://realpython.com/python-csv/

Comment: When you have determined your objective on parsing the CSV files as well as coming up with a code for it, you can post a new question and the community will be glad to help! :)

Comment: Yes I'd like to translate the csv file row by row so I believe the right parsing would be combine string per row. Thank you for your answer!